# Представить результат MySQL-запроса в виде Map

Tags: java, mysql

Есть таблица статей со структурой:

```
id       - ID
text     - Текст статьи
user_id  - ID пользователя добавивиший статью
created  - дата создания в формате Y-m-d H:i:s
```

Данные в таблице:

```
id | text    | user_id  | created
----------------------------------------------
1  | Text 1  |     1    | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
2  | Text 2  |     2    | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
3  | Text 3  |     3    | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
```

и таблица комментарий к статьям со структурой:

```
id          - ID
text        - Текст комментария
article_id  - ID статьи
user_id     - ID пользователя добавивиший комментарий
created     - дата создания в формате Y-m-d H:i:s
```

Данные в таблице:

```
id | text         | article_id   | user_id   | created
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Comment 1.1  |     1        |     1     | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
2  | Comment 2.1  |     2        |     2     | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
3  | Comment 3.1  |     3        |     3     | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
4  | Comment 1.2  |     1        |     1     | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
5  | Comment 2.2  |     2        |     2     | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
6  | Comment 3.3  |     3        |     3     | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
7  | Comment 1.3  |     1        |     1     | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
8  | Comment 2.3  |     2        |     2     | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
9  | Comment 3.3  |     3        |     3     | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
```

`LEFT JOIN` запросом получаю результат

```
a_id | a_text | comment_text | created
-------------------------------------------------------------
  1  | Text 1 | Comment 1.1  | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
  2  | Text 1 | Comment 1.2  | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
  3  | Text 1 | Comment 1.3  | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
  4  | Text 2 | Comment 2.1  | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
  5  | Text 2 | Comment 2.2  | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
  6  | Text 2 | Comment 2.3  | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
  7  | Text 3 | Comment 3.1  | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
  8  | Text 3 | Comment 3.2  | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
  9  | Text 3 | Comment 3.3  | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
```

Как этот результат представить в виде **Map < Artice, List <Comment> >** ?

Comment: а ты как пробовал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грубо говоря, получится что-то вроде этого:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.execute();
Map<Article, List<Comment>> map = new HashMap<Article, List<Comment>>();
while (rs.hasNext()) {
    Article a = new Article(rs.getString("a_text"));
    List<Comment> comments = map.get(a);
    if (comments == null) {
        comments = new LinkedList<Comment>();
        map.put(a, comment);
    }
    Comment c = new Comment(rs.getString("comment_text"));
    comments.add(c);
}
```

Обязательно, чтобы в классе `Article` был реализован метод `equals`, желательно, чтобы ещё был реализован метод `hashCode`, вычисляющий хэш объекта по тексту. Для упрощения сравнения статей лучше в выборку добавить id статьи и записывать его в объект при создании. Тогда сравнивать можно будет только по id.

Comment: Поясните, пжст, строчку:

    Article a = new Article(rs.getString("a_text"));

Вы при каждой итерации создаете новый Article? А потом его ищите в Map'е?

Comment: Именно это я и делаю. По условию ключом `map`-а является `Article`, поэтому для поиска значения приходится создавать объект `Article`. И именно поэтому просто необходим нормальный метод `equals` в `Article` - без него в `map`-е могут оказаться два идентичных по содержимому объекта. Этот код можно несколько оптимизировать, если в классе `Article` будет поле `id`, в которое мы будем выбирать id статьи. В этом случае метод `equals` должен сравнивать объекты по id. Тогда можно не пихать в создаваемый объект весь текст статьи, а только id.

Comment: Само собой, если в `map`-е ещё нет объекта с таким id, то в него придётся записать текст.

Comment: Понятно, это неэффективный алгоритм. Зачем создавать каждый раз и искать каждый раз, когда мы идем по комментариям одной и той же статьи? По крайней мере реализуется сортировкой в запросе. 

1. Итерация n (например первая). Создаем статью, пишем в нее комментарий.
2. Итерация n+1. 
2.1. Если статья поменялась, создаем новую, пишем в нее комментарий.
2.2. Если статья не менялась пишем комментарий в старую.

Никаких дополнительных методов при этом не нужно.

Comment: Если будет несколько уровней группировок, создается массив с группировками, по которым определяется в текущей группе мы находимся или надо подняться на несколько уровней выше.

Comment: @fori1ton, Спасибо Получилось.